# Password Protecting SQLite Database in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am working on an Android App which requires importing and exporting of SQLite Database. I have to protect the database as it contains crucial data . I have thought of encrypting and decrypting the database. But I want to know is it possible to password protect the SQLite database so that whenever the user wants to access the database he/she will be required to enter the password first.

Comment: i think you are looking something similar to password protected PDF, but its not possible. Encryption-Decryption is best idea. Still if you want password protected than you can do setup on your own in the app but it won't make any difference to accessing database its just you are authorizing user to access database

Comment: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/